# How to block Google ads from appearing in tests

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright, google-ads-script

How to block Google ads appearing in tests.

To get around the adverts I use:
`await page.frameLocator('iframe[name="aswift_2"]').frameLocator('iframe[name="ad_iframe"]').getByRole('button', { name: 'Close ad' }).click();`
Which doesn't always work, so I use:
`await page.goBack(); await page.goForward();`
works as I use each test separately, but when I run all the tests in sequence then ads appear in new test locations and the tests don't pass
How can I write a script to disable Google adverts
I am learning to test in Playwright on the app https://automationexercise.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adblocker-playwright](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cliqz/adblocker-playwright).

Or block network resources that generate Ads. See [Playwright network docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#abort-requests)

```js
  await page.route("**/*", route => {
    route.request().url().startsWith("https://googleads.") ?
      route.abort() : route.continue();
    return;
  })
```